# Nginx $request_time and $upstream_response_time in Windows

Tags: logging, nginx

I'm encountering some weirdness in my access log running Nginx on Windows.  I've included $request_time in my access log as well as $upstream_response_time (running Django as fcgi upstream).  It's my understanding that the log should represent request time in milleseconds, but it's output looks like this:

```
ip|date|request_time|upstream_response_time
xx.xx.xx.xxx|[29/Jan/2013:15:29:57 -0600]|605590388736.19374237|0.141
xx.xx.xx.xxx|[29/Jan/2013:15:30:39 -0600]|670014898176.19374237|0.156
```

Any ideas what the heck that gigantic number is!?

Here's the full log format (I removed a few columns in teh above example)

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr|$time_local]|$request|$request_time|$upstream_response_time|'
                  '$status|$body_bytes_sent|$http_referer|'
                  '$http_user_agent';
```

Using pipe delimiters.

Comment: Can you show how your `log_format` directive looks like?

Comment: done!  i removed a few columns for clarity in the example, but the question now has the whole log format

Comment: And this log file is for presented log format? It doesn't look like :/

Comment: in the the example log output i did not include all of the columns to declutter it.  The example output is for '$remote_addr|$time_local|$request_time|$upstream_response_time'

Comment: you are getting such values for `$request_time` everytime or only with `post` requests?

Comment: Looking deeper at the data, I get those kinds of huge values any time there is a non-zero value in the upstream_response_time.  For example, a row with an upstream_response_time of 0.172 has a request_time of 738734374912.194, another with 0.156 has request_time of 670014898176.194.  But any time the upstream_response_time has 0.00, the request_time is ALWAYS 0.19374237

Comment: In other words when upstream is not doing it works, yes? You could check it this way: look into your log and do request with get that upstream time will be 0 and see after how many sec it will apear in log file. Next do post request which involves upstream and see after how many sec it will appear in log. Due nginx doc $request_time with post will be calculcated after whole response is comple so if for some reasone anything is still opened on your upstream it wont print it into log unlead connection closed and it could happend after very long time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Put that in the Answer and I'll mark you "Correct"!

Comment: Hi @bwooceli, I am also facing with similar problem. Were you able to pinpoint the source of the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So as you suggest here comes the answer:

When you make request to your server (`nginx` + `upstream`) as GET then `$request_time` result with normal and acceptable value. That happens because your upstream server doesn't take part in it and even if it does it makes it properly.

Problems start when you are doing POST request. According to nginx doc value of `$request_time` variable (available only at logging) will be compute when all data have been send and connection have been closed (by all upstreams and proxy also). And only then info is appended to log.

So how to check if everything is correct? 
First do a GET request to your server and watch log file. Notice how much time it really takes to finish the call and add log info into file - it should be real value.
Next do a POST request to your server and watch log file again. Here, probably, you will see that log isn't coming at all or after very long period.

What it means? Check your nginx conf and your upstream conf because somewhere could be a place where connection isn't closed and just hang in the air. Those connection could be renew after time by your OS or upstream server but after all it could cause some problems other than just strange `$request_time` value.

Comment: `$request_time:
request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution; time elapsed between the first bytes were read from the client and the log write after the last bytes were sent to the client` ... so this measure slow clients. The recommendation is to ignore it in favour of `$upstream_response_time`